# An URL I want to post is blacklisted

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I try to post my message with hyperlink or simple link, I want help some people, but I see the next message: Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because: Sorry, posts can't contain that content. Tell me what it's all about?

Answer (score 6):

You *might* want to check out zlatan24 's post history to see what kind of "content" he is trying to post.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/412976/zlatan24

quite cheeky, really, to complain here.

Comment: Funny to read *"But a friend advised me [...]"* when he's always posting links to products on the same site.

Comment: Wow, that's *really* cheeky.

Comment: **DELETED!** :(

Answer (score 1):

It means that to avoid spam and possible [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks, not all types of content are allowed. This included many HTML tags.

StackOverflow uses a system called [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), so you can use that. There is an orange question mark at the top right of the editing textbox that will give you markdown syntax help.

I suggest you read the whole [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), so see how things work.

Comment: in this case, he's really trying to post a spam blacklisted URL

Comment: @oded well, just follow the question back to the parent site and click on the user profile...

Comment: @Jeff - will try to do some more due-diligence when answering such questions in the future.